# Populate the views with Array

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I am new to Android.
I found this code in my book that i am learning from. Its not explained properly
I created a Drink java class
and then i used `drinks[]`in my activity. On click it passes the Id of the clicked Array to another activity using intent.
Now in that other activity i want to display the name of the drink the image and the description that we stored in the array
I understood that we have stored the array Id in the Drinks class object
but why did we use the getter methods to get the name and descprition and the image.
They are not linked with the array?
They have no code inside them?
Then what is actually happening

### can someone explain?

`Drinks.java` class code

```
Class Drinks
{
 private String name ;
    private  String  description ;
    private  int rid ;

    public static final Drinks[] drinks = {
            new Drinks("Latte", "A couple of espresso shots with steamed milk",
                    R.drawable.latte),
            new Drinks("Cappuccino", "Espresso, hot milk, and a steamed milk foam",
                    R.drawable.cappuccino),
            new Drinks("Filter", "Highest quality beans roasted and brewed fresh",
                    R.drawable.filter)
    };


          public Drinks(String name, String description, int rid) {
                this.name = name;
                this.description = description;
                this.rid = rid;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return description;
            }

            public int getRid() {
                return rid;
            }
        }


-----------------------------------------
```

The activity code where i am using the drinks[] and passing its Id

```
    listDrinks = findViewById(R.id.listDrinks);



    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,Drinks.drinks);
    listDrinks.setAdapter(adapter);
    listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this , Main3Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

---

The other activity where i am passing the array id and using getter methods to set name description and image to display

```
  textView = findViewById(R.id.textname);
    text_description = findViewById(R.id.text_description);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.photo);


    Intent intent= getIntent();
 int drinkId = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id"));
    Drinks d = Drinks.drinks[drinkId];


    textView.setText(d.getName());

    text_description.setText(d.getDescription());


    imageView.setImageResource(d.getRid())

;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making new objects inside the Drinks[] drinks,which will call the constructor of that class and set the name, description and rid which are private. So you need getter functions to access that particular objects rid,name and description. You are only parsing the id of object to be accessed in your second activity.